# Modify WooCommerce product columns

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to override, or simply customize, the admin orders list view.

I understood the method to customize is `render_shop_order_columns` in includes/admin/class-wc-admin-post-types.php but I cannot remove the action (method) from theme functions.php neither by a custom plugin in the `plugins_loaded` hook: always get `bool(false)` on

```
var_dump(remove_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', array( $GLOBALS['wc_admin_post_type'], 'render_shop_order_columns' ) ));
```

I see there is the `woocommerce_order_item_name` filter, but if I add a picture there (that's what I need), I get a wrong output since it is used in the title attribute of link to product too.

Could anyone please advice?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a wrong way...
Maybe the right one is to unset the column and add your own.
See here:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/hooking-and-adding-new-column-on-woocommerce-order-admin-page

basically:

```
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'show_custom_product_column', 15);

function show_custom_column($columns) {

    $new_columns = (is_array($columns)) ? $columns : array();

    //remove column
    unset($new_columns['column_to_unset']);

    //add custom column
    $new_columns['custom_column'] = __( 'Translation', 'woocommerce' );

    return $new_columns;
}

add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'my_custom_column', 10, 2);

function my_custom_column($column) {

    global $post, $woocommerce, $the_order;

    switch ($column) {

        case 'custom_column' :
        // Custom code
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the better way. I was in the process of answering exactly this.